# How define named native query in xml with spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am using spring boot, I would like to define the native query in xml files.
Here is the entity:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findAllUsers",query = "select * from user")
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "UserId")
    private Integer userId;
}
```

And the Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
    @Query(name="findAllUsers")
    List<User> findAllUsers();
}
```

I want to switch native sql quickly between native-sql-oracle.xml and native-sql-mysql.xml.

Comment: JPA supports a file "orm.xml". It is in any JPA docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a **.hbm.xml** file in the resources directory, it will be auto scanned by spring。

A sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <package>com.xxx.auth</package>
    <entity class="User">
        <named-native-query name="searchUser" result-class="User">
            <query>
                <![CDATA[
                SELECT * FROM User
                ]]>
            </query>
        </named-native-query>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

Comment: For me it worked with the file inside a resources/META-INF/ folder